# Learning graphics/gaming on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, opengl-es, core-graphics

I wanted to learn some graphics and thereby gaming coding in iPhone. I have experience in Nav/Tab/View based applications but never worked on OpenGL or Quartz.

Could anyone guide my way to this new exciting journey of graphics. Please suggest tutorials, session videos, example videos... basically anything that could help me understanding the related concepts.

PS: I have a developer account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple good and **free** resources:

- [WWDC 2012 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/) - In particular: "Advances in OpenGL and OpenGL ES" and "OpenGL ES Tools and Techniques"
- [Core Animation - Simplified Animation Techniques for Mac and iPhone Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321617754) - Book on Core Animation and Quartz 2D
- [iPhone 3D Programming](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596804824/) - Book on OpenGL
- [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) - Thorough Apple documentation on OpenGL and it's integration with iOS
- [All About OpenGL 2.x](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/01/all-about-opengl-es-2-x-part-13/) - Three part series (beginner, intermediate, advanced), so very thorough
- [Quartz 2D Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html) -  Apple's own documentation on Quartz
- [18 OpenGL ES Resources That You Must Know!](http://maniacdev.com/2009/10/18-opengl-es-resources-that-you-must-know/) - Good collection with not only OpenGL resources but also mathematics for 3D graphics
- [The Categorized OpenGL ES Tutorial Collection](http://maniacdev.com/2009/09/the-categorized-opengl-es-tutorial-collection/) - Collection of over 50 tutorials and guides
- [OpenGL ES from the Ground Up](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/opengl-es-from-ground-up-table-of.html) - Great beginner tutorial
- [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/) - A great site with a great community and many resources

Those are couple good books and videos. Also make sure to check out [Ray Wenderlich's site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/); it contain's many good, complete tutorials for beginners. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you also consider using Cocos2d, Box2d or something similar. Here is a good book.

[http://www.amazon.com/Learning-Cocos2D-Hands-On-Building-Chipmunk/dp/0321735625/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1341100387&sr=8-2&keywords=cocos2d](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321735625)

Ray Wenderlich also has a game programming starter kit on their website which you could consider buying - http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/space-game-starter-kit